# MS Access combobox lookup causing strange record # behaviour

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, lookup

So I'm relatively new to MS Access but have developed a relatively comprehensive CRM tool for my organization that allows users to record company employees, organization details, and meeting details.

I've run into an odd problem with my "Edit Organization" form. When I use the unbound lookup combobox to change records, it loads up the new record correctly; however, the record number showing at the bottom of the page appears to be random... for example if I select the 6th record using the lookup box, it might show as record number 96 (or something else totally random).

I'm not super concerned by this (although somewhat); however, one of the other odd behaviours is that the lookup works for all records except when changing back to the first organization in the database. In this case, it doesn't load the EmployeeID and related information properly (but this is fine for all other records in the database).

Any suggestions would be great. The code the page is as below. I'm sure there is some extraneous code in there at the moment, but none of it should affect this I don't think...

```vb
'Updates the Phone and Email text boxes when the Employee is changed in the dropdown menu
Private Sub cboEmployee_Change()
    Me.txtPhone.Value = Me.cboEmployee.Column(2)
    Me.txtEmail.Value = Me.cboEmployee.Column(3)
    Me.cboRelationship.Value = Null
    Me.cboBranch.Requery
    Me.cboMinistry.Requery
    Me.cboDivision.Requery
End Sub

'Updates the Phone and Email text boxes when the Employee is changed in the dropdown menu
Private Sub cboEmployee_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtPhone.Value = Me.cboEmployee.Column(2)
    Me.txtEmail.Value = Me.cboEmployee.Column(3)
    Me.cboRelationship.Value = Null
    Me.cboBranch.Requery
    Me.cboMinistry.Requery
    Me.cboDivision.Requery
End Sub

'Requeries the various other boxes on the form after a Ministry is selected and clears the Phone and Email fields. Bit of a hack to use Employee 43 (blank vs. null)
Private Sub cboMinistry_Change()
    Me.cboDivision.Value = Null
    Me.cboBranch.Value = Null
    Me.cboDivision.Requery
    Me.cboBranch.Requery
    Me.cboEmployee.Requery
    Me.txtPhone = Null
    Me.txtEmail = Null
End Sub

'Requeries the various other boxes on the form after a Division is selected and clears the Phone and Email fields. Bit of a hack to use Employee 43 (blank vs. null)
Private Sub cboDivision_Change()
    Me.cboMinistry.Requery
    Me.cboBranch.Requery
    Me.cboEmployee.Requery
    Me.txtPhone = Null
    Me.txtEmail = Null
    Me.cboRelationship.Value = Null
End Sub

'Requeries the various other boxes on the form after a Branch is selected and clears the Phone and Email fields. Bit of a hack to use Employee 43 (blank vs. null)
Private Sub cboBranch_Change()
    Me.cboDivision.Requery
    Me.cboMinistry.Requery
    Me.cboEmployee.Requery
    Me.txtPhone = Null
    Me.txtEmail = Null
    Me.cboRelationship.Value = Null
End Sub      

'Populates the form with the appropriate details if there is an EmployeeID associated with an organization
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.cboLookup.Value = Organization
If IsNull(EmployeeID) = True Then
    Me.cboMinistry.Value = Null
    Me.cboDivision.Value = Null
    Me.cboBranch.Value = Null
    Me.txtPhone.Value = Null
    Me.txtEmail.Value = Null
Else
    Me.cboEmployee.Value = EmployeeID
    Me.cboBranch.Value = BranchID
    Me.cboDivision.Value = DLookup("DivisionID", "tblBranch", "BranchID=" & BranchID)
    Me.cboMinistry.Value = DLookup("MinistryID", "tblDivision", "DivisionID=" & Me.cboDivision)
    Me.cboEmployee.Requery
    Me.cboBranch.Requery
    Me.cboDivision.Requery
    Me.txtPhone.Value = PhoneNumber
    Me.txtEmail.Value = Email
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The combobox and form records are not in same order? Is there filter applied to either set? The record position in combobox will not necessarily be the same record position in the form. Sounds like normal behavior to me. Are txtPhone and txtEmail UNBOUND? No need to use VBA to populate. Expression in ControlSource property can reference the combobox column.

Comment: My combobox is sorted by OrganizationID and shows up in the same order as the records in tblOrganization, so shouldn't the record indicator at the bottom of the form show the same number as the record entry in tblOrganization? It's also weird that it works for all records except when I use the combobox to go back to the first record in tblOrganization, at which point it fails to properly load the EmployeeID.

On the side note, txtPhone and txtEmail are unbound. I can't recall exactly why I did that at the moment, but ya, that's why they're being populated/nulled using the VBS...

Comment: By 'record entry' do you mean the OrganizationID? Is this an autonumber field? The intrinsic record indicator on form has NO connection to a value in table field. It is simply a record counter for the form's recordset. Did you try expression in ControlSource as suggested? Set breakpoints in the code you expect to execute when going back to first record. Is the code triggered?

Comment: I think that what I was looking at is the record counter. Good to know that it doesn't have any relation to anything in the recordset. Thanks!